# When I add new element to the array, new cost in cont registered

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I learning Angular and I have first problem. My service look like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { COSTInterface } from './COSTSInterface'
import {Costs} from './mock-cost'

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CostService {

  getCosts(): Observable<COSTInterface[]> {
    return of(Costs);
  }

  getBalance(): Observable<number> {
    let balance = 0;
    this.getCosts().subscribe(costs => {
      for (const cost of costs) {
        if (cost.type === 'income') {
          balance += cost.cost;
        } else {
          balance -= cost.cost;
        }
      }
    });
    return of(balance)
  }

  add(element: COSTInterface): void {
    Costs.push(element)
  }

  getCount(): Observable<number>{
    return of(Costs.length);
  }
  constructor() { }
}
```

OK. I can add new element to the array

```
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [0],
    name: [''],
    type: [''],
    cost: [0]
  })
  count:number = 0;

  getCount() {
    this.costService.getCount().subscribe(count => {
      this.count = count + 1;
    })
  }
  onSubmit() {
    const newCost: COSTInterface = {
      id: this.count || 0, // Jeśli wartość jest null lub undefined, ustawiamy 0 jako domyślną wartość
      name: this.profileForm?.value.name || '',
      type: this.profileForm?.value.type || '',
      cost: this.profileForm?.value.cost || 0
    };

    this.costService.add(newCost)
  }
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private costService: CostService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getCount();
  }
```

But the balance is not calculated automatically when a new element is added.

Summary Component when I have the balance is very simple and looks like this

```
  balance:number = 0;

  getBalance(): void {
    this.costService.getBalance().subscribe(balance => {
      this.balance = balance;
    });
  }
 constructor(private costService: CostService){}
 ngOnInit() {
   this.getBalance();
 }
```

can guess where the problem is, but I have no idea how to solve it. Propably service's method getBalance don't know that we change array of costs but I don't know how solve this problem.

How can I display new  total cost after I add new element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CostService.getBalance is not handling asynchronous events properly. Rewrite it this way:

```
  getBalance(): Observable<number> {
    return this.getCosts()
               .pipe(map(costs => {
      let balance = 0;
      for (const cost of costs) {
        if (cost.type === 'income') {
          balance += cost.cost;
        } else {
          balance -= cost.cost;
        }
      }
      return balance;
    }));
  }
```

It makes the "getBalance" return the correct balance amount. But it wouldn't retrigger when a new cost is added. For this, you need BehaviorSubjects:

```
  private balance$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0); // 0 is default value)
  constructor(/*someStuff*/) {
    // init balance
    this.updateBalance();
  }

  getBalance(): Observable<number> {
    return this.balance$.asObservable();
  }

  private updateBalance() {
    this.getCosts()
        .subscribe(costs => {
      let balance = 0;
      for (const cost of costs) {
        if (cost.type === 'income') {
          balance += cost.cost;
        } else {
          balance -= cost.cost;
        }
      }
      // triggers the event to all subscribers
      this.balance$.next(balance); 
    }));
  }

  add(element: COSTInterface): void {
    Costs.push(element);
    this.updateBalance();
  }
```